# Word order of "is it" in questions

Tags: questions, word-order

Which one is correct?

- > Is it good or *is it* bad?
- > Is it good or *it is* bad?

I am pretty sure that the first one is correct, but are there any cases in which the second one would be a valid option too? I could not manage to answer this using Google, since I was able to find millions of examples of both cases.

Comment: My google search returned 68,600 instances of the first sentence, but only 5 of the second. Make sure you use quotes.

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty sure the **first is correct** and **the second isn't**.
Generally "or" is used for similar structures/words, phrases, and clauses with the same grammatical type.

> According to [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/or):

> Or is a conjunction that connects two or more possibilities or alternatives. It connects words, phrases and clauses which are the same grammatical type:

e.g. Which do you prefer? Leather or suede?

e.g. You can have some freshly baked scones or some chocolate cake or both.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).